# How to close static ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, static, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have a class with a static ComboPooledDataSource field which I initialize in the static block

```
public class MyDataSource {

    private static ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    static {
        try {
            cpds.setDriverClass("org.h2.Driver");
            cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
            cpds.setUser("user");
            cpds.setPassword("password");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            // handle the exception
        }
    }
    
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return cpds.getConnection();
    }
    
    private MyDataSource(){} }
```

With this approach, the ComboPooledDataSource is instantiated when the MyDataSource class loaded. My understanding is that the class will not be unloaded unless its classloader is garbage collected and that will only happen when none of its loaded classes are in use.

The documentation for c3p0 states that we should cleanup the datasource when it's not needed anymore and if we fail to do so, the datasource's finalize() method will be called whose behavior isn't always reliable.

https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#using_combopooleddatasource

I wanted to close the ComboPooledDataSource when MyDataSource class is unloaded or reloaded but I think there isn't a way to achieve that. If that is correct, is there another approach I could take to manage cleanup? One idea I came across was that I could change the MyDataSource class to a singleton and then use its finalize method for cleanup. However, I don't think that is an improvement because the ComboPooledDataSource is already being called at GC time.

Comment: A `ComboPooledDataSource` has a `close()` method (inherited through `PooledDataSource`) you can use.

Comment: I know, thanks. I edited the question to make it clearer. The idea is to have the ComboPooledDataSource remain open as long as the MyDataSource class is loaded. I want to be able to close ComboPooledDataSource on class unload or use a similar approach.

Comment: If your class is unloaded, then `ComboPooledDataSource` becomes eligible for garbage collection, and its finalizer should then close it for you. The behaviour of finalizers is not unreliable, it is just not predictable when finalization runs, and at application exit they might not run. However,  if the application exits, it isn't really important as the program ends anyway. Personally, I think you shouldn't really worry about this, or you need to switch to something a little more reliable for lifecycle management, like Spring.